# Which answers would be a valuable addition to the tikz/pgf manual to document existing features

Tags: discussion, big-list

This site is an amazing resource for those who are interested in `tikz/pgf`.

Sometimes, the official manual is not as clear as it could be and some important piece of information are given here.

So I'd like to list the answers that could complete the manual. The added content to the manual could result in a link to the site, cited as further reading.

I would suggest on answer per answer. Please add the section of the manual where you think the content would fit most.

Obviously, what I'm trying to do here won't be doable if this list is too large to maintain...

Comment: Depending on the "success" of this question, I have two others in mind: a big-list of feature requests based on code provided here and a  big-list of documentation for the internal code based on answers.

Answer (score 7):

The user discovering the `calc` library may be interested in advanced usage of it (pros and cons). See Andrew's answer (and his warnings): [Combining |- and !.5! in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29734/combining-and-5-in-tikz/29781#29781)

Section of the manual: Coordinate calculations.

Comment: I'm tempted to say - based partly on the analysis behind that answer but also on a common type of question we get here - that a good section in the manual would be a description of how some of the key components of TikZ work.  I'm thinking of the parsers such as `\tikz@scan@one@point` and `\tikz@next@command`.  Perhaps not in detail, but at least to show how they interact with TeX groupings and the like.

Answer (score 6):

My [first tikz question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5494/is-there-a-tikz-style-for-putting-math-in-all-nodes) and still my most popular has an answer that, by analogy with several features that *are* explained in the manual, should definitely be in the manual.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a TikZ question, but, since they are written by the same group, here is a Beamer question that would be useful to have addressed in the Beamer user guide: [How do I add custom beamer actions that change an argument?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6584/how-do-i-add-custom-beamer-actions-that-change-an-argument)  It seems that the description of custom actions is incomplete, and possibly incorrect.